# Utilizar enlace de carpeta compartida en PHP

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tengo el siguiente codigo el cual me envia un correo con el enlace de una carpeta compartida para ver fotografias tomadas con una aplicacion movil y almacenadas en esta carpeta, pero cada que pongo la direccion como `\\ipservidor\carpetaimg\'.$nombre.'` en el correo me aparece sin el primer `\` por lo cual no logro abrir la carpeta.

La variable $nombre es para redireccionar a la carpeta que se genera de las fotos ya que dependiendo del nombre se genera una carpeta diferente.

```
    $bodyMessage = [ 

    'subject' => '< Reporte de Imagenes ><  >< App Control Equipo >',
    'body' => '
    <div>
        <br><br>
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <td><strong>Evidencia de carga de caja:</strong></td></tr>
            <td>Buen dia</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td> Se genero link de carpeta de fotografias del registro # '.$nombre.'</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <a href="\\ipserver\Fotografias\"'.$nombre.'"">\\ipserver\Fotografias\"'.$nombre.'"</a>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>De final de turno </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Saludos!</td>
            </tr>
                    
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <i><u>Por favor, no responda este mensaje</u></i>
        </div>
        <div>
            <i><u>webmaster:</u></i>
            <a href="mailto:mail">mail</a>
        </div>

        Saludos!

    </div>',

    ];
```

Pero cuando me llega el correo no puedo abrir el enlace por que lo muestra de la siguiente manera `\ipservidor\Fotografias\juan`

Me podrian auxiliar

Comment: Si el destinatario del email no tiene acceso DIRECTO a la carpeta compartida, cómo podría verla?

Comment: La carpeta esta como compartida ya probe el link en un 2do equipo y si habre la direccion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El caracter `\` es un caracter de escape. Entonces para escapar un caracter de escape se usa otro `\`.

Una ruta local Windows sería:

```php
$var1 = 'C:\\Directorio\\archivo1.jpg';
```

Una ruta remota:

```php
$var2 = '\\\\ruta_servidor\\share\\archivo1.jpg';
```

Plus: Aunque sea Windows, puedes usar `/`

```php
$var1 = 'C:/Directorio/archivo1.jpg';
$var2 = '//ruta_servidor/share/archivo1.jpg';
```

Nota: En el caso de la concatenación de rutas, en PHP existe una constante llamada `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` que define el tipo de separador de rutas del sistema operativo. Si quieres hacer una función cross-platform usa el separador `/` o la constante.

Comment: yo recomendaria usar la constante...

Comment: Gracias me funciono